# SQLite: too many SQL variables

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite, flask, apache-superset

I have installed Apache Superset on an AWS EC2 instance as outlined here - https://superset.apache.org/docs/installation/installing-superset-from-scratch.

When I run the `superset load_examples` command, I get the following error. This runs fine on my local computer but doesn't work on EC2 for some reason. The error says 'too many variables', but there are only 7 variables.

The SQL Alchemy version are as follows:

```
SQLAlchemy==1.3.22
SQLAlchemy-Utils==0.36.8
```

Error Log:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ec2-user/superset/venv/lib64/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1277, in _execute_context
    cursor, statement, parameters, context
  File "/home/ec2-user/superset/venv/lib64/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 609, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
sqlite3.OperationalError: too many SQL variables

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ec2-user/superset/venv/bin/superset", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(superset())
  File "/home/ec2-user/superset/venv/lib64/python3.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 829, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ec2-user/superset/venv/lib64/python3.7/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 586, in main
    return super(FlaskGroup, self).main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ec2-user/superset/venv/lib64/python3.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 782, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "/home/ec2-user/superset/venv/lib64/python3.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1259, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
  File "/home/ec2-user/superset/venv/lib64/python3.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1066, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "/home/ec2-user/superset/venv/lib64/python3.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 610, in invoke
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ec2-user/superset/venv/lib64/python3.7/site-packages/click/decorators.py", line 21, in new_func
    return f(get_current_context(), *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ec2-user/superset/venv/lib64/python3.7/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 426, in decorator
    return __ctx.invoke(f, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ec2-user/superset/venv/lib64/python3.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 610, in invoke
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ec2-user/superset/venv/lib64/python3.7/site-packages/superset/cli.py", line 172, in load_examples
    load_examples_run(load_test_data, only_metadata, force)
  File "/home/ec2-user/superset/venv/lib64/python3.7/site-packages/superset/cli.py", line 116, in load_examples_run
    examples.load_birth_names(only_metadata, force)
  File "/home/ec2-user/superset/venv/lib64/python3.7/site-packages/superset/examples/birth_names.py", line 94, in load_birth_names
    load_data(tbl_name, database, sample=sample)
  File "/home/ec2-user/superset/venv/lib64/python3.7/site-packages/superset/examples/birth_names.py", line 78, in load_data
    index=False,
  File "/home/ec2-user/superset/venv/lib64/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 2615, in to_sql
    method=method,
  File "/home/ec2-user/superset/venv/lib64/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py", line 598, in to_sql
    method=method,
  File "/home/ec2-user/superset/venv/lib64/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py", line 1406, in to_sql
    raise err
  File "/home/ec2-user/superset/venv/lib64/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py", line 1398, in to_sql
    table.insert(chunksize, method=method)
  File "/home/ec2-user/superset/venv/lib64/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py", line 830, in insert
    exec_insert(conn, keys, chunk_iter)
  File "/home/ec2-user/superset/venv/lib64/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py", line 758, in _execute_insert_multi
    conn.execute(self.table.insert(data))
  File "/home/ec2-user/superset/venv/lib64/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1011, in execute
    return meth(self, multiparams, params)
  File "/home/ec2-user/superset/venv/lib64/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/elements.py", line 298, in _execute_on_connection
    return connection._execute_clauseelement(self, multiparams, params)
  File "/home/ec2-user/superset/venv/lib64/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1130, in _execute_clauseelement
    distilled_params,
  File "/home/ec2-user/superset/venv/lib64/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1317, in _execute_context
    e, statement, parameters, cursor, context
  File "/home/ec2-user/superset/venv/lib64/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1511, in _handle_dbapi_exception
    sqlalchemy_exception, with_traceback=exc_info[2], from_=e
  File "/home/ec2-user/superset/venv/lib64/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 182, in raise_
    raise exception
  File "/home/ec2-user/superset/venv/lib64/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1277, in _execute_context
    cursor, statement, parameters, context
  File "/home/ec2-user/superset/venv/lib64/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 609, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) too many SQL variables
[SQL: INSERT INTO birth_names (ds, gender, name, num, state, sum_boys, sum_girls) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)]
[parameters: ('1965-01-01 00:00:00.000000', 'boy', 'Aaron', 369, 'CA', 369, 0, '1965-01-01 00:00:00.000000', 'girl', 'Amy', 494, 'CA', 0, 494, '1965-01-01 00:00:00.000000', 'girl', 'Andrea', 607, 'CA', 0, 607, '1965-01-01 00:00:00.000000', 'boy', 'Andrew', 933, 'CA', 933, 0, '1965-01-01 00:00:00.000000', 'girl', 'Angela', 1066, 'CA', 0, 1066, '1965-01-01 00:00:00.000000', 'girl', 'Anna', 564, 'CA', 0, 564, '1965-01-01 00:00:00.000000', 'boy', 'Anthony', 1928, 'CA', 1928, 0, '1965-01-01 00:00:00.000000', 'girl', 'Barbara', 922, 'CA', 0, 922, '1965-01-01 00:00:00.000000', 'boy', 'Bradley', 395, 'CA', 395, 0, '1965-01-01 00:00:00.000000', 'girl', 'Brenda', 961, 'CA', 0, 961, '1965-01-01 00:00:00.000000', 'boy', 'Brian', 2233, 'CA', 2233, 0, '1965-01-01 00:00:00.000000', 'boy', 'Bryan', 542, 'CA', 542, 0, '1965-01-01 00:00:00.000000', 'boy', 'Carlos', 401, 'CA', 401, 0, '1965-01-01 00:00:00.000000', 'girl', 'Carol', 816, 'CA', 0, 816, '1965-01-01 00:00:00.000000', 'girl', 'Carrie', 367, 'CA', 0, 367, '1965-01-01 00:00:00.000000', 'girl', 'Catherine', 706, 'CA', 0, 706, '1965-01-01 00:00:00.000000', 'boy', 'Charles', 1609, 'CA', 1609, 0, '1965-01-01 00:00:00.000000', 'girl', 'Cheryl', 1052, 'CA', 0, 1052, '1965-01-01 00:00:00.000000', 'girl', 'Christina', 848, 'CA', 0, 848, '1965-01-01 00:00:00.000000', 'girl', 'Christine', 1450, 'CA', 0, 1450, '1965-01-01 00:00:00.000000', 'boy', 'Christopher', 2322, 'CA', 2322, 0, '1965-01-01 00:00:00.000000', 'girl', 'Cindy', 842, 'CA', 0, 842, '1965-01-01 00:00:00.000000', 'boy', 'Craig', 874, 'CA', 874, 0, '1965-01-01 00:00:00.000000', 'girl', 'Cynthia', 1947, 'CA', 0, 1947, '1965-01-01 00:00:00.000000', 'girl', 'Dana', 546, 'CA', 0, 546, '1965-01-01 00:00:00.000000', 'boy', 'Daniel', 2641, 'CA', 2641, 0, '1965-01-01 00:00:00.000000', 'boy', 'David', 6820, 'CA', 6820, 0, '1965-01-01 00:00:00.000000', 'girl', 'Dawn', 962, 'CA', 0, 962, '1965-01-01 00:00:00.000000', 'girl', 'Deborah', 1610, 'CA', 0, 1610, '1965-01-01 00:00:00.000000', 'girl', 'Debra', 1153, 'CA', 0, 1153, '1965-01-01 00:00:00.000000', 'girl', 'Denise', 1423, 'CA', 0, 1423, '1965-01-01 00:00:00.000000', 'boy', 'Dennis', 801, 'CA', 801, 0, '1965-01-01 00:00:00.000000', 'girl', 'Diana', 864, 'CA', 0, 864, '1965-01-01 00:00:00.000000', 'girl', 'Diane', 947, 'CA', 0, 947, '1965-01-01 00:00:00.000000', 'boy', 'Donald', 1388, 'CA', 1388, 0, '1965-01-01 00:00:00.000000', 'girl', 'Donna', 1270, 'CA', 0, 1270, '1965-01-01 00:00:00.000000', 'boy', 'Douglas', 972, 'CA', 972, 0, '1965-01-01 00:00:00.000000', 'boy', 'Edward', 1280, 'CA', 1280, 0, '1965-01-01 00:00:00.000000', 'girl', 'Elizabeth', 1676, 'CA', 0, 1676, '1965-01-01 00:00:00.000000', 'boy', 'Eric', 2241, 'CA', 2241, 0, '1965-01-01 00:00:00.000000', 'boy', 'Frank', 930, 'CA', 930, 0, '1965-01-01 00:00:00.000000', 'boy', 'Gary', 1441, 'CA', 1441, 0, '1965-01-01 00:00:00.000000', 'boy', 'George', 924, 'CA', 924, 0, '1965-01-01 00:00:00.000000', 'boy', 'Gregory', 1669, 'CA', 1669, 0, '1965-01-01 00:00:00.000000', 'girl', 'Heather', 404, 'CA', 0, 404, '1965-01-01 00:00:00.000000', 'boy', 'Jack', 361, 'CA', 361, 0, '1965-01-01 00:00:00.000000', 'girl', 'Jacqueline', 690, 'CA', 0, 690, '1965-01-01 00:00:00.000000', 'boy', 'James', 5060, 'CA', 5060, 0, '1965-01-01 00:00:00.000000', 'girl',.....)]
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/13/e3q8)
```

Answer (score 0):

That's curious sqlite3 max parameter value is 999, and can only be changed by recompiling it (SQLITE_MAX_VARIABLE_NUMBER).

Please note that Apache superset does not actively support sqlite and this engine is not advised for production. Take a look at: https://www.sqlite.org/whentouse.html

> If many threads and/or processes need to write the database at the same instant (and they cannot queue up and take turns) then it is best to select a database engine that supports that capability, which always means a client/server database engine.